# Paginated Report - From and To Date Range Parameter

Tags: parameters

I have a paginated report that points to a dataset.  I have a filter on the date in the date dimension table using range inclusive option.  This creates my from and to date parameters.  These from and to date parameters are set as text because the dax query has logic to conver to datetime to do the comparison.  My report runs and returns data, but it always returns data just for the date that is the 'to' date.  i.e, if I select the from as 6/30/2022 and the to as 8/31/2022, the report only returns ddata for 8/31/2022 even though I know there is data for other months. I can run it for other months, and it always returns data just for the 'to' date.  I even changed the date parms to date/time and still get the same results.  Any ideas why?  I have researched this a lot and tried many things but no success.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let everyone know I was able to figure this out.  All I did was within query designer, I added a random measure from my model onto the column list, and that fixed the problem.  I compared the two DAX queries side by side and the only difference I see is that the measure I added shows up on my list of columns selected; i.e, no other difference between the two DAX queries but for some odd reason adding any random measure fixes the issue.  Thanks